# Problems connecting to SVN Repository with Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svn-repository

I have to connect with an SVN Repository from Eclipse, using Subclipse plugin but I can't.

I can access through browser and TortoiseSVN but every time I try with Eclipse I get "timedout" error.

Through TortoiseSVN it takes a while but I can make it, so I'm thinking it may be a problem of timeout configuration with Subclipse. It stays "connecting" like 5 or 10 minutes, then throws the error. I tryed changing the **servers** file from **AppData\Roaming\Subversion**, uncommenting the line:

```
http-timeout=120
```

But still can't connect.

NOTE: I can't post the URL of the repository because it's from work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to configure a proxy server or something?  It sounds like your repository URL is http or https?  The Subclipse code uses the same libraries as TortoiseSVN so should work the same and respond to the same settings, though TortoiseSVN is able to configure some settings in its UI that you have to configure in the Subversion servers and config file when using Subclipse.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have Eclipse configured with dinamyc proxy option (I tried direct option also), I didn't made any special configuration for it (neither for TortoiseSVN).
I'm working with VPN and company proxy, but I assumed the configuration is the same for TortoiseSVN and for Eclipse. So, if I can access from TortoiseSVN (or browser), why not from Eclipse?

UPDATE: I forget to answer. Yes, my URL is HTTP, is that something important?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a C++ app and has access to more of the Subversion API than Subclipse does.  It is able to auto-configure things that Subclipse cannot.  The proxy configuration for Subclipse has to be done the same way it is done for the SVN command line client which is via the servers and config files in the runtime configuration area.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could finally solve the issue. It was a problem of Eclipse proxy configuration, as you said.